# Intellij community edition 2019.2.4 unable to import gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea

The import fails with the below message:

```
Could not create parent directory for lock file <C:\Program Files\Gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.5-bin\f1w0cc9nuo0eivz97x2xlu9sv\gradle-7.5-bin.zip.lck>
```

It is getting imported with Spring tool suite without any such issues.

Comment: Please check if the problem reproduces in the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: works with the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue not found in latest version